# Send notification through facebook application using rest fb api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, restfb

I am trying to send notification to facebook users via facebook application using restfb api. When tried to publish such notification, it shows an exception

```
"com.restfb.exception.FacebookGraphException: Received Facebook error response of type 
GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request".
```

Below is my code:

```
FacebookType = facebookAppAccessToken.publish("user_id/notification?access_token=app_access_token"), 
FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("template","send_notification"), 
Parameter.with("href,"sample_link"));
```

Please help me resolving this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
public void sendNotification(String externalUserId, String message) {
    AccessToken appAccessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient()
            .obtainAppAccessToken(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(
            appAccessToken.getAccessToken());
    try {
        facebookClient.publish(externalUserId
                + "/notifications", FacebookType.class,
                Parameter.with("template", message));
    } catch (FacebookOAuthException e) {
        if (e.getErrorCode() == 200) {
            //Not an app user
        } else if (e.getErrorCode() == 100) {
            //Message cannot be longer than 180 characters
        }
    }
}
```

Handle error codes appropriately. And you can add href and ref as per your requirement. 
[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/#impl) are Details of parameters.